# How quickly would a slug with 25% human dna dissolve in salt water?

Tags: biology, creature-design

Pretty soon i’m going to have to write a slug-human hybrid thats falls more under the slug category dissolving in the ocean. So i’m asking if a slug with about 25-35% human dna would dissolve any slower or faster than a regular slug in salt water.

Slugs are burned by salt. Things like wasps, worms, and slugs are burned by chemicals and toxics. But with how human skin is able to withstand salt directly unless its on an open wound, i’m wondering if slug with human dna will have stronger skin and be able to tank direct contact with salt for longer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would depend a lot on exactly which 25% was human and not slug DNA.  The possibility space is so large that we have no way of answering this.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean by dissolve either. You should be aware that this site works best if you tell us what you're trying to achieve, then we can help you get there - it's really not clear at present if you want slug-folk to "dissolve" more or less quickly. Could you fill us in on what you're goal is and what you mean.

Comment: The vast overwhelming majority of slugs are [sea slugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_slug), and they most definitely do not dissove in sea water.

Answer (score 8):

Humans and bananas share about 40 to 60 percent of the same DNA. Yet, if I get a blow on my body, it doesn't turn black within minutes, nor I get more ripe by standing next to apples.

That is to say, the % of DNA has little to do with the reaction to the environment, unless it is exactly the DNA coding for the skin, which however would make it pretty hard for the slug to be a slug, because, well, slug moves and acts like a slug thanks to not having a human like skin.

And, by the way, salt on human skin dries it through osmosis, just slower than what it does to slugs. That's how corpses were preserved sometimes in the past. So I'd be careful in assuming that salt is harmless for humans.

Comment: If it is not the apples then how is you are getting more ripe?  SO very ripe?